# How to pass the name of the file as a parameter to the controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

how can i pass the id as the name.I used this code.

```
 <?php 
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($view as $row)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
            echo "<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/play/songs/<?php echo $row->audio"><td>". $row->audio . "</td>";

            $i++;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
       ?>
```

I want to play the song when user press the name of the song.but i am not able to pass the name of the song to my controller "play".so please help and this is my controller where i want to pass the data.

```
class Play extends CI_Controller {


    public function songs($name){
        $data['name'] = $name;
        $this->load->view('admin/play',$data);


    }
```

Comment: Could you add your controller code? Additionally, describe what information each $row object stores.

Comment: Use the Edit link to add code to the OP rather than posting code within comments.

Comment: Perhaps you should follow [the CodeIgniter tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html), which gives a working example about how to pass a parameter from View to Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should grab id instead of name it will make your job easier.

```
<?php 
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($view as $row)
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$i."</td>";
            echo "<a href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/play/songs/<?php echo $row->id"><td>". $row->audio . "</td>";

            $i++;
            echo "</tr>";
        }
       ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should know that you can pass the url you want after base_url as a parament in base_url like

```
base_url('admin/play/songs/');
```

Secondly you can pass anything to controller via this method

```
 base_url('admin/play/songs/{$row->audio}');
```

Just excited to know if it works

Comment: ya it worked....but i should pass the id rather then its name is't it..........@Rabis Naqvi